# Get rid of .php ending in Lighttpd

Tags: lighttpd

I just installed Lighttpd and PHP onto my Raspberry Pi using [this guide.](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2013/06/how-to-setup-a-web-server-on-your-raspberry-pi/)

It's working great,  and I have a nice little website going. However, I would like to get rid of the annoying .php endings on all the URLs. Since Lighttpd doesn't support .htaccess files, I don't know how to do this.

As I am not an expert, you might have to be very specific on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your `/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf` file:

```
index-file.names        = ( "index.html",  "default.html",                     
                            "index.php",   "default.php" )
```

After you update your `lighttpd.conf`, restart lighttpd.